# Obtener el precio total y global en android studio utilizando mysql y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, recyclerview

Buen día tengo un problema al momento de calcular el precio total y global en Android Studio.

Vamos desde el inicio tengo un RecyclerView el cual lleno con productos desde una pantalla anterior, cada ítem del `Recyclerview` tiene su `total` su cantidad su nombre y el botón mas y menos para calcular la cantidad.

El problema radica principalmente en que no setea correctamente la cantidad del cada item y la cantidad total de todos los items; el otro problema es que el boton `mas` solo funciona una vez, o sea, asigna la nueva cantidad pero cuando quiero volver a asignar una nueva cantidad, no lo hace se queda con lo mismo.
Sin mas aquí muestro mi código explicado.

Esta es mi clase adaptador y mostrare directamente el holder donde tengo la lógica.

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull adapProdReport.ProdReportViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tvNombre.setText(listaProdReport.get(position).getNombreProducto());
        lDetMonto = listaProdReport.get(position).getMonto();
        lDetMontoIva = listaProdReport.get(position).getMontoIva();
        lPrecioVta = listaProdReport.get(position).getPrecioVenta();

        holder.tvPrecio.setText(formatoDecimal.format(lPrecioVta));

        lCantPorducto = listaProdReport.get(position).getCantiProd();
        holder.tvCantidad.setText(Double.toString(lCantPorducto));
        lDetMontoFinal = lDetMonto + lDetMontoIva;
        holder.totalItem.setText(formatoDecimal.format(lDetMontoFinal));

        //holder.btnMenos.setEnabled(false);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> refreshView(position));

        holder.btnMas.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            //holder.btnMenos.setEnabled(true);
            double counter = Double.parseDouble(holder.tvCantidad.getText().toString());
            ++counter;
            holder.tvCantidad.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

            lidDetPedido = listaProdReport.get(position).getIdDetPedido();
            lDetMontoFinal = listaProdReport.get(position).getPrecioVenta() * listaProdReport.get(position).getCantiProd();

            try {
                new ActualizarCantidad(holder.itemView.getContext()).execute().get();
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Double newSubTotal = lPrecioVta + lDetMontoFinal;
            //TicketDatos.gTotal = TicketDatos.gTotal + lDetMontoFinal;

            holder.totalItem.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));
            //TicketDatos.totalFinal.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));

            TicketDatos.subTotalReporte.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));
            TicketDatos.totalFinal.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));


        });

        holder.btnMenos.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            double counter = Double.parseDouble(holder.tvCantidad.getText().toString());
            if (counter > 1.0) {
                --counter;
                holder.tvCantidad.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            }
            if (counter == 1.0){
                holder.btnMenos.setEnabled(false);
            }

            lidDetPedido = listaProdReport.get(position).getIdDetPedido();
            lDetMontoFinal = listaProdReport.get(position).getPrecioVenta() * listaProdReport.get(position).getCantiProd();

            try {
                new ActualizarCantidad(holder.itemView.getContext()).execute().get();
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Double newSubTotal = lPrecioVta - lDetMontoFinal;
            //TicketDatos.gTotal = TicketDatos.gTotal + lDetMontoFinal;

            holder.totalItem.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));
            //TicketDatos.totalFinal.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));

            TicketDatos.subTotalReporte.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));
            TicketDatos.totalFinal.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));

        });

        holder.btnEliminar.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            lidDetPedido = listaProdReport.get(position).getIdDetPedido();
            lDetMontoFinal = listaProdReport.get(position).getMonto() + listaProdReport.get(position).getMontoIva();

            try {
                new EliminarDetPedido(holder.itemView.getContext()).execute().get();
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //if(EliminarDetPedido.exitoDeleteProd == true) {

            Double newSubTotal = TicketDatos.gTotal - lDetMontoFinal;
            TicketDatos.gTotal = TicketDatos.gTotal - lDetMontoFinal;

            TicketDatos.subTotalReporte.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));
            TicketDatos.totalFinal.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));

            removeAt(position);

            //}

            int decremento = Integer.parseInt(ObtenerProductos.tvCantProductos.getText().toString());
            decremento = decremento - 1;

            AdaptadorProductos.tvCantProductos.setText(String.valueOf(decremento));

        });
    }
```

En esta parte

> holder.tvNombre.setText(listaProdReport.get(position).getNombreProducto());
> lDetMonto = listaProdReport.get(position).getMonto();
> lDetMontoIva = listaProdReport.get(position).getMontoIva();
> lPrecioVta = listaProdReport.get(position).getPrecioVenta();

Solo obtengo los datos del modelo debido a que obtengo todo desde una base de datos `MySQL`

En esta parte

> holder.tvPrecio.setText(formatoDecimal.format(lPrecioVta));
> lCantPorducto = listaProdReport.get(position).getCantiProd();
> holder.tvCantidad.setText(Double.toString(lCantPorducto));
> lDetMontoFinal = lDetMonto + lDetMontoIva;
> holder.totalItem.setText(formatoDecimal.format(lDetMontoFinal));

Solo obtengo los datos del modelo para posteriormente hacer el calculo del IVA

**Y aquí está la parte más importante. Es donde tengo el botón `+` y botón `-` para calcular la cantidad de cada item y, a su vez, la cantidad global:**

```
    holder.btnMas.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        //holder.btnMenos.setEnabled(true);
        double counter = Double.parseDouble(holder.tvCantidad.getText().toString());
        ++counter;
        holder.tvCantidad.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

        lidDetPedido = listaProdReport.get(position).getIdDetPedido();
        lDetMontoFinal = listaProdReport.get(position).getPrecioVenta() * listaProdReport.get(position).getCantiProd();

        try {
            new ActualizarCantidad(holder.itemView.getContext()).execute().get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Double newSubTotal = lPrecioVta + lDetMontoFinal;
        //TicketDatos.gTotal = TicketDatos.gTotal + lDetMontoFinal;

        holder.totalItem.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));
        //TicketDatos.totalFinal.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));

        TicketDatos.subTotalReporte.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));
        TicketDatos.totalFinal.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));


    });

    holder.btnMenos.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        double counter = Double.parseDouble(holder.tvCantidad.getText().toString());
        if (counter > 1.0) {
            --counter;
            holder.tvCantidad.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        }
        if (counter == 1.0){
            holder.btnMenos.setEnabled(false);
        }

        lidDetPedido = listaProdReport.get(position).getIdDetPedido();
        lDetMontoFinal = listaProdReport.get(position).getPrecioVenta() * listaProdReport.get(position).getCantiProd();

        try {
            new ActualizarCantidad(holder.itemView.getContext()).execute().get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Double newSubTotal = lPrecioVta - lDetMontoFinal;
        //TicketDatos.gTotal = TicketDatos.gTotal + lDetMontoFinal;

        holder.totalItem.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));
        //TicketDatos.totalFinal.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));

        TicketDatos.subTotalReporte.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));
        TicketDatos.totalFinal.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));

    });
```

Por último, tengo el boton eliminar este lo agregue ya que funciona de forma correcta y quiza esto ayude un poco a entender mejor el codigo

```
    holder.btnEliminar.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        lidDetPedido = listaProdReport.get(position).getIdDetPedido();
        lDetMontoFinal = listaProdReport.get(position).getMonto() + listaProdReport.get(position).getMontoIva();

        try {
            new EliminarDetPedido(holder.itemView.getContext()).execute().get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //if(EliminarDetPedido.exitoDeleteProd == true) {

        Double newSubTotal = TicketDatos.gTotal - lDetMontoFinal;
        TicketDatos.gTotal = TicketDatos.gTotal - lDetMontoFinal;

        TicketDatos.subTotalReporte.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));
        TicketDatos.totalFinal.setText(formatoDecimal.format(newSubTotal));

        removeAt(position);

        //}

        int decremento = Integer.parseInt(ObtenerProductos.tvCantProductos.getText().toString());
        decremento = decremento - 1;

        AdaptadorProductos.tvCantProductos.setText(String.valueOf(decremento));

    });
}
```

De antemano muchas gracias.